# How do you send an image attachment on an ios app with swift using mailgun?

Tags: iphone, swift, mailgun

I was able to send a regular email with a body text using a cocoapod
https://cocoapods.org/?q=mailgun
But is there a way to send an image attachment?

Answer (score 2):

According to it's [SDK](https://github.com/rackerlabs/objc-mailgun) (which sadly hasn't been improved for Swift and has a dependency on AFNetworking which is objc):

```
let message = MGMessage(from:"Excited User <someone@sample.org>",
                            to:"Jay Baird <jay.baird@rackspace.com>",
                            subject:"Mailgun is awesome!",
                            body:"Mailgun is great, here is a picture of a cat.")!
// someImage: UIImage
// type can be either .JPEGFileType or .PNGFileType
message.add(someImage, withName: "image01", type:.PNGFileType)
```

[SwiftMailgun](https://github.com/PiXeL16/SwiftMailgun) seems like a better fit for Swift but it's still in early stages (Check the TODO list).

Comment: Is there a way to do it programmatically without the use of this cocoapod?

Comment: Without the official SDK ? Sure. You need to use their REST API.

Comment: I can't find any libraries related to swift in their API

Comment: Because there aren't any. You'll need to use the official objc one, SwiftMailgun or create your own

Comment: Quick rewrite of the objc version in swift: [MailgunSwift](https://github.com/bre7/mailgun-swift) Sending attachments is working fine. If you encounter any issues, open a new one in the repo